# Upgrade to 18.04 from 16.10

Tags: 18.04, 16.10

I have an ETL/database server running on a 16.10 system. I get errors when trying to apt install packages so I’d like to upgrade. Is it safe to do so?  It looks like I need to run commands to edit files.

Database has streaming replication and I rsynced all of my files (I hope) to another system.

Comment: The tested procedure for upgrades from 16.10 was to 17.04 (now EOL), then 17.10 (also EOL), then to 18.04 LTS (where you could continue to upgrade to each release, or stay on the LTS path).  The intended & tested procedure is now closed to you so you're upgrade is now untested (and that skipping releases is not supported).  You should do your own testing & validation on [database] program migration as you're outside of tested paths.